# Find the limit in distribution of the sequence $\{Z_n\}_{n \in N}$

Tags: probability

To be honestly, I have no idea what I should do for this question. It would be great if someone can help me.

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $Z_{n}$ be a discrete random variable with a point probability given by $$P(Z_{n}=\frac{i}{n})=\frac{1}{n}$$ $$i=1,...,n$$

Find the limit in distribution of the sequence $\{Z_n\}_{n \in N}$. Is it a known distribution?

I know the definition of convergence in distribution is

$X_n \rightarrow X $ (in distribution) if
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} F_{X_n}(x)=F_X(x)$$ for all $x$ such that $F_X(x)$ is continuous.

I understand that I must first find $F_{X_n}(x)=P(Z_{n}\leq x)$, but i don't know how to start.

I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Note that we have an explicit formula for $F_{Z_n}$: $$ F_{Z_n}(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x<0,\\\lfloor nx\rfloor/n,&0\leq x\leq1,\\1,&x>1.\end{cases}$$ Can you compute its pointwise limit as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @SangchulLee $$\lim_{n \to \infty}F_{Z_n}(x)=\begin{cases}0 & ,x\leq 0 \\ x &, 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\1 &, x \geq 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Perfect! So the limit in distribution of $Z_n$ is any random variable $Z$ whose CDF is given by that limit. Now all you have to do is whether you can identify this limit as a CDF of some familiar distribution. (*Spoiler alert:* It is a familiar distribution.)

Comment: @SangchulLee 
It is distributed $U(0,1)$ ?

Comment: That is correct :) You figured out the answer. It also intuitively makes sense, because if you pick a uniformly random number from a fine mesh of numbers between $0$ and $1$, it will look just like it is sampled from a uniform distribution. (This is roughly how a random number between $0$ and $1$ is sampled in computers.)

Comment: @SangchulLee Woooow, thank you very much !!